# Return result as true if all the individual letters of pattern appear in string

Tags: javascript

How do I ensure that the following code returns true if all the individual letters of pattern appear in string (regardless of order, case sensitive and ignoring symbols and numbers).

```
var s = "abcdef"
var p = "@C2D!"

function match(string, pattern) {

    var count = 0;
    if (pattern) {

        for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++) {
                if ((string.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase().charAt([j]))) < 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count == 0) return (true);
        else return (false);
    }
    else {
        return ("");
    }
}

alert(match(s, p));
```

Comment: It would probably be more organized to sort both strings as lists of characters, eliminate duplicates, eliminate strings in the target that aren't in the pattern, and then confirm that they're the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
function match(string, pattern) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(pattern.indexOf(string[i]) === -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
alert(match("abcdef", "@C2D!"));
```

or with RegExp:

```
function match(string, pattern) {
    pattern = pattern.replace(/\]/g,'\\]').replace(/\^/g,'\\^').replace(/\-/g,'\\-');
    return RegExp('^['+pattern+']+$','i').test(string);
}
alert(match("abcdef", "@C2D!"));
```

**Edit**: Oops! I didn't read you want to ignore symbols and numbers!

But then your question is not well-defined:

- Do you want to ignore them in string, pattern or both?
- What exactly is a symbol? Are `ÄÈéï` and `ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ` letters or symbols?

Comment: I just want to ignore anything that is not a,b,c

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not filtering out simbols. Possible solution

```
function match(string, pattern) {
    var i, letter, rex,
        match = false;

    for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        letter = pattern.charAt(i);
        if (letter.match(/[\d|\W]/)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            match = true;
            rex = new RegExp(letter, "i");
            if (!string.match(rex)) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return match;
}

var s = "abcdef"
var p = "@F2D!=="

console.log(match(s, p));
```